# Protovis JavaScript doesn't work in dropdownlist onchange event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, protovis

I noticed the following problem. When I remove either block of code, either one works well but when I put them together, only one of it worked.

I am trying to call a method from a `dropdownlist` using the `onchange` event but its fails when my code for Protovis/JavaScript is added.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function getDate()
        {
            alert("dateValue");
        }
        
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript+protovis">
  function Colour(color) {
  new pv.Panel()
  .width(12)
  .height(20)
  .anchor("center").add(pv.Dot)
  .strokeStyle(null)
  .fillStyle(color)
  .radius(5)
  .root.render();
   }

</script>

<select name="mydropdown" onchange="getDate(this)">
<option value="None">Select Date</option>
</select>
```

I want to get both of them to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

The above code works as expected here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/NAEku/

*But*, when I actually call the `Colour()` function elsewhere on the page, there's an error, and my guess is that's the root of your problem. The issue here is that when you use a `script` block with `type="text/javascript+protovis"`, it gets eval'd by the Protovis library *after* the page is fully loaded - so any functions or variables you define in a `javascript+protovis` block won't be available in the global scope for normal script blocks further down the page.

So my guess is that you're trying to call `Colour()` before the Protovis block has been evaluated. The quick fix for this example, since you're not using any special Protovis syntax, is to just change the `script` block to `type="text/javascript"`, which will cause it to be evaluated normally.

Updated, functional jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/NAEku/1/